# Will the Sql Server Import And Export Wizard have shapefile support anytime soon?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

Do you know?

PS: Some of you will tell me to check the Sql Server Management Studio features roadmap. But where is it?

Comment: Related feature request at Microsoft Connect: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=217943

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I the Social Msdn there's a simmilar question, you can see the answer.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlspatial/thread/12b4d06e-0336-4dbc-bfdf-48fcfe5e834c/